# React: Passing a value from componentDidMount to render()

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and getting confused between react hooks. There are many similar questions asked and I tried a few answers but it didn't work. I am trying to use a value of flag which has been set in componentDidmount() in render(). But I am getting undefined. Here is my code. Can someone help me?

```js
export default class Shop extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isContentTypeShop1: false,
    };

  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const basketContextData = await fetchBasketContext(); // returns json object
    const basketContentType = basketContextData.basketContentType; //returns string 'shop1'
    console.log(basketContentType) 
    if(basketContentType === 'shop1') {
      this.isContentTypeShop1 = true;
    } 
    console.log(this.isContentTypeShop1); // returns true
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.isContentTypeShop1); //returns undefined
    return (
      <ul className="progress-bar">
        
        <li>
          
          {(this.isContentTypeShop1) && ( // hence doesn't work
              <span>
                Shop 1
              </span>
           )}
          </li> 
        
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to go through few trainings before you start working on new technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of setState to trigger a re-render from componentDidMount. Also `isContentTypeShop1` isn't a class variable but its a `state`

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const basketContextData = await fetchBasketContext(); // returns json object
    const basketContentType = basketContextData.basketContentType; //returns string 'shop1'
    console.log(basketContentType) 
    if(basketContentType === 'shop1') {
      this.setState({isContentTypeShop1: true});
    } 
  }

render() {
  // use it from state
  console.log(this.state.isContentTypeShop1);
}
```

Comment: Ohhh that helped! I had tried to set up state but wasn't using it from there in render. I am still studying React will get there :) Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to have helped vinita.

Answer (score 1):

`this.isContentTypeShop1` doesn't exist because `isContentTypeShop1` is inside state. Try this instead:

```
console.log(this.state.isContentTypeShop1);
```

And to update `isContentTypeShop1`, you need to call setState:

```
this.setState({ isContentTypeShop1: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this.state.isContentTypeShop1` instead of `this.isContentTypeShop1` & you can't set state using `=`

You need to use `setState` like `this.setState({ isContentTypeShop1: true })`

You need to read **Using State Correctly** part from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

And for some [additional](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-react-setstate/) [reading](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781/) :)